# Regular expression to match a time-span

Tags: regex, timespan

I want to parse data which might contain mixed patterns like

```
1-4pm
1pm-5pm
noon to 11pm
noon to midnight
etc.
```

I want to extract start and end time. How can I achieve this through regex. I know I can't support all possible input formats, but how can I achieve to support a maximum?

---

this is my expression

```
^((?<dayPart>[a-z]+)?)\s*(?<startTime>[0-9]{1,2}[:]?[0-9]{0,2}\s*[am|pm|a.m|p.m]*[.]*)?\s*[-|to|\\|/|=]*\s*((?<endPart>[a-z]+)?|(?<endTime>[0-9]{1,2}[:]?[0-9]{0,2}\s*[am|pm|a.m|p.m]*[.]*))?$
```

which covers almost all combination.

I just want to know if there is any optimization in this regex.

Here `dayPart` will consume all starting non-digit characters to handle if time-span starts with noon, midnight etc or any value which we can ignore like Sunday.
`startTime` will try to consume any time in any format if it is there. same is for `endPart` and `endTime`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, define a pattern that matches a single point in time. Given your examples it might be something like:

```
(noon|midnight|[0-9]+\s?(am|pm)?)
```

Next, define the separator. Perhaps:

```
(to|\-)
```

Finally, combine two of the first with one of the second. Assuming your language supports variables, something like:

```
set timePattern {(noon|midnight|[0-9]+\s?(am|pm)?)}
set separator {(to|\-)}
set fullPattern "$timePattern(\s*$separator\s*$timePattern)?"
```

Once you pass that through the engine you should be able to get at the parts of the expression that matched. You might need to make some groups non-capturing but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader. You'll then likely have to parse the individual parts to figure out the time. For example, parse "1pm" as a 1 and "pm" and calculate a time based on that.

Once you have it broken down like that it makes it easier to fiddle with the constituent parts and makes the expression a bit more comprehensible. Though, the same thing can be accomplished in some languages that support multiline expressions with comments.

Comment: You shouldn't escape the dash in the separator expression, that's unnecessary. +1 for the approach.

Comment: You are correct that, strictly speaking, it's not necessary. It's a habit I've gotten myself into since you have to treat "-" specially in a range. I tend to automatically protect it everywhere. <shrug>

Answer (score 1):

Depending on language, you can 'build-up' a matching pattern. 
Ruby, for example, will allow you to do something like:

```
time_spec = /noon|midnight|\d{1,2}/
sep = /-|to/
match = /#{time_spec}\s*#{sep}\s*#{time_spec}/
```

But, since this seems like something that will be much more complex as it gets extended, why not create some sort of parser (using flex/yacc?) that will maintain much better than a regex? 
When you start supporting a range of input such as 1pm/1p/13:00/13 regex start creating more problems then solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Without much to go on, it looks like you can split based on `"-"` or `"to"`.

```
^(.+) ?(-|to) ?(.+)$
```

That will capture the start time in the first group and the end time in the third. If you want a more specific syntax, you'll have to specify which variant of regex you intend to use.

Comment: The greedy "+" is a bit problematic. I think it's better to change at least the first paren to `(.+?)`. But I take it as read that this is what you mean by "you'll have to specify which variant of regex". ;-)